# Find exact value regarding a Fourier Series

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined by $$f(x) = \sin|x| + 5\sin(2013x)$$ if $-\pi < x < \pi$ and $f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$ for all $x \subseteq R$.
Let $$a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx))$$ be the Fourier series for $f(x)$.

Find the exact value of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$$

---

I understand that $\sin|x|$ is an even function and $5\sin(2013x)$ is an odd function, thus we only need to take the latter into consideration when finding values relevant to $b_n$. However, how should I go about finding the summation from $n=1$ to infinity?

Update: I understand that since $5\sin(2013x)5\sin(2013x)$ is an odd function, both $a_0$ and the summation involving $a_n$ will be zero since our period is from $-\pi < x < \pi$. Thus we'd be left with the summation of $b_n\sin(n2x)bn\sin(\frac{n}{2}x)$ from $n = 1$ to infinity. Is the aforementioned correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe focus on what the Fourier series for $\sin(2013 x)$ can be...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hi, would I be correct to say that since $5sin(2013x)$ is an odd function, both $a_0$ and the summation involving $a_n$ will be zero since our period is from $-\pi < x < \pi$. Thus we'd be left with the summation of $b_n sin(\frac{n}{2}x)$ from $n=1$ to infinity?

Comment: To continue with Yves's line of thought: There are some functions that have a very simple Fourier series. For example the Fourier series of $1$ is just $1,$ the Fourier series of $\cos 4x$ is just  $\cos 4x$  etc.

Comment: @zhw. Hi zhw, thanks for the prompt but I am struggling to derive the proof for the $cos4x$ case... I know it is probably something really simple but I'm just.. not getting it as of now.. Are you able to point me in a specific direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

By inspection, the infinite system of equations in $a_n,b_n$
$$a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos(nx) + b_n\sin(nx))=5\sin(2013x)$$

has an obvious solution.

---

If you prefer the "hard way", use

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(mx)\cos(nx)\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(mx)\sin(nx)dx=\pi\delta_{mn},$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(mx)\sin(nx)\,dx=0.$$

Comment: Wow.. that's an interesting way to approach the question. I can see that by comparison, when $n = 2013$, Summation of $b_n = 5$, is that right? However, how should I go about proofing that when $n \neq 2013$, $b_n = 0$? Would I have to evaluate the integral as written by @JezuzStardust above to proof that? Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: @stephchia: I wrote all you need, but you still missed the obvious point.

Comment: Can you solve $a+b\cos x+c\sin x+d\cos 2x+e\sin 2x+f\cos3x+g\sin 3x=4\sin 2x$ ?

Comment: Hi... this is probably as frustrating for you as it is for me currently but I am indeed failing to see the obvious point you're stating to guide me to solving the question, and I'm not sure about the above either.. :/ (sigh)

Comment: Using the result that @YvesDaoust wrote the only thing you need to prove is that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin |x| \sin(n x) = 0$ for all $n$. To do this a hint is to consider if the integrand is an even or an odd function.

Comment: @stephchia: please write down the solution of the given identity.

Comment: Hi @JezuzStardust , I understand that the integrand is an odd function since we are multiplying an even function $sin|x|$ with an odd function $sin(nx)$, and that would give us zero. However, this part of the understanding only lead me to knowing that $sin|x|$ should be excluded from our workings, I am still missing the obvious point that YvesDaoust is trying to make that would allow me to proof that when $n \neq 2013$, $b_n = 0$... Do you have any tips for that? I appreciate Yves' guidance but at this point I'm too lost to follow any further...

Comment: I think I will update my response with a proof of this. See above in a few minutes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Hi, may I know for which one are you referring to?

Comment: @stephchia: which one what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which given identity do you want me to find the solution for?

Comment: @stephchia: the one in my comments.

Comment: @stephchia: last attempt: can you solve the identity $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3=4x^2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust If we let $x = 1$, we get $a + b + c + d = 4$, I'm sorry but is that the solution you were trying to get me to see in the sense that I could say, let $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ for the main equation you posted or otherwise..?

Comment: @stephchia: need to give all $4$ coefficient values. You are making it harder than necessary.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ugh omg I'm blur as a lamb. That would give $a = 0$, $b = 0$, $c = 4$, $d = 0$. Does that mean that, with reference to the question, in order to get $5sin(2013x)$, $b_n = 0$ for all $n$ except $n = 2013$, and for the remaining, we have $b_{2013} = 5$ in order to satisfy the equation?

Comment: @stephchia: you got it. The Fourier series of a sinusoid is trivial. It has no harmonics.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I really appreciate your patience and help, but could you help to clarify if I get this right from top-down: Given that we want to find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$, we would only concern ourselves with the odd function part of $f(x)$ which is $5sin(2013x)$. However by observing the function and comparing with $b_n sin(nx)$ we realize that we are looking at the nth term being 2013 and the bnth term equating to 5 whilst the rest of the terms in the infinite series equates to zero in order for the summation to hold true. Would that be right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48647/discussion-between-stephchia-and-yves-daoust).

Comment: @stephchia: I already confirmed, let us stop here.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks so much for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To find the sum over $b_n$ I would suggest first calculating them. Use that 
\begin{equation}
b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \sin(nx) dx 
\end{equation}
As already pointed out in the comments the part with $\sin |x|$ should not contribute to this, but it is always a good idea to check this explicitly. As soon as you have calculated $b_n$ you can perhaps find the value of the sum, by using what you know about e.g. geometrical series. However, in this case, you will find that $b_n \neq 0$ only for a single $n$, can you guess which one? Hence the summation will be trivial.

A useful relation is the following
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(mx) \sin(nx) dx = \delta_{nm}
\end{equation}
To prove this integral, we can use the trigonometric relation $\cos(a \pm b) = \sin(a) \sin(b) \mp \cos(a) \cos(b)$. Taking the difference between these two equations with the different signs we get 
\begin{align}
\cos(a + b) - \cos(a - b) &= \cos(a) \cos(b) - \sin(a) \sin(b) - \cos(a) \cos(b) - \sin(a) \sin(b) \\ &= - 2 \sin(a)\sin(b)
\end{align}
Hence we get that 
\begin{equation}
\sin(mx) \sin(nx) = \frac{1}{2} \left\{ \cos[(m-n) x] - \cos[(m+n) x] \right\}. 
\end{equation}
Now we need to consider the two different cases where $n = m$ and $n \neq m$ separately. However, the resulting integrals are very easy. E.g. if $n \neq m$ we get 
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(mx)\sin(nx)dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \left\{ \cos[(m - n ) x] - \cos[(m+ n)x] \right\} dx = 
\\ 
\left. \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\sin[(m-n)x]}{m - n} - \frac{\sin[(m+n)x]}{m+n} \right) \right|_{-\pi}^\pi = 0 
\end{align}
To check the case where $n=m$, insert this into the integrand and you will see that the integral above is $\pi$ in that case.

Comment: Hi, I am embarking on the arduous journey of finding $b_n$ currently. May I know if, since our $f(x)$ is an odd function and the multiple of odd functions, such as the case of that within the integral, yields an even function - that we could change the limit from $-\pi < x < \pi$ to $0 < x < \pi$ by multiplying the whole function by 2?

Comment: Hi, I've so for gotten $$\frac{5}{\pi} ( \frac{sin(2013-n)\pi}{2013-n} - \frac{sin(2013+n)\pi}{2013+n})$$ but I don't seem to find a way for $n = 2013$ to stand out as a unique case... Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hi there, I've followed your integrals and reached $$\frac{5}{\pi} ( \frac{sin(2013-n)\pi}{2013-n} - \frac{sin(2013+n)\pi}{2013+n})$$ as written above, but I am failing to see how we could get an integral of $\pi$ from the above, I understand that we will get 0 on the left side since $sin0 = 0$, but for the other side how should I approach it?

Comment: Use that $\sin ( n \pi) = 0$ for any integer $n$. $2013 \pm n$ is an integer if and only if $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Regarding your previous question, you must go back to the integral expression when considering the case $m = n$, otherwise you get division by zero.

Comment: Ah, I got it now, thanks alot!!